# Error while loading the library event after export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, ubuntu, lib

When i execute one necessary step in my project:

```
ubuntu@cscsh:~$ soss dds_to_ros2.yaml 
\Error while loading the library ["/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-dds/lib/soss/dds/../../libsoss-dds.so"]: /home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-dds/lib/soss/dds/../../libsoss-dds.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps28DisablePositiveACKsQosPolicyE
Could not find system handle for middleware of type [dds]
Failed to load middlewares!
```

So i do this:

```
ubuntu@cscsh:~/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-dds/lib$ ldd libsoss-dds.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff5ef61000)
    libfastrtps.so.1 => /home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastrtps/lib/libfastrtps.so.1 (0x00007f8ae4179000)
    libsoss-core.so => /home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-core/lib/libsoss-core.so (0x00007f8ae3de1000)
    libyaml-cpp.so.0.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5 (0x00007f8ae3b67000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8ae3948000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8ae35bf000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8ae33a7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8ae2fb6000)
    libfastcdr.so.1 => /home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastcdr/lib/libfastcdr.so.1 (0x00007f8ae2da3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8ae2b9f000)
    libtinyxml2.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml2.so.6 (0x00007f8ae298b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8ae4aae000)
    libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 (0x00007f8ae270a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8ae236c000)
```

then execute command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastrtps/lib

ubuntu@cscsh:~/ros2_ws/src/eProsima$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-ros2-test/lib:/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-ros2/lib:/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-mock/lib:/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-json/lib:/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-dds/lib:/home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-core/lib:/home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastcdr/lib:/home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastrtps/lib
```

But when i execute: soss dds_to_ros2.yaml.
The same error message still exists.
Does anyone know what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not finding the library.  It is that your library is missing a symbol was expected.  There is a good chance that you simply have the wrong version of the library installed. What you want to do is run the following:

```sh
# You will need the full path if you are not in that directory...
objdump -Tt /home/dbt/rosis_workspace/soss/install/soss-dds/lib/libsoss-dds.so | \
grep -w _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps28DisablePositiveACKsQosPolicyE
```

You will probably see something like:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps28DisablePositiveACKsQosPolicyE
```

This is correct, but it means that this symbol is not defined in this library, but it expects to find it within one of the libraries that `ldd` listed for you.  My first guess would be `libsoss-core.so`, but we are looking for incompatible versions and this library seems to have the same root directory as `libsoss-dds.so`, so these versions should definitely be compatible.  If you want to see if a library contains a specific symbol, just run `objdump` the way I did above.  After a quick internet search for that library symbol, I was brought to a [github issue page](https://github.com/ros2/demos/issues/368) for `ros2`.  This leads me to believe that the culprit library is actually `libfastrtps.so.1`.  If you run the following:

```
objdump -Tt /home/dbt/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/install/fastrtps/lib/libfastrtps.so.1 | \
grep -w _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps28DisablePositiveACKsQosPolicyE
```

and the library contained the symbols that `libsoss-dds.so` is looking for, this would be your result:

```
0000000000002cc0 g    DF .text  0000000000000011  Base        _ZTVN8eprosima8fastrtps28DisablePositiveACKsQosPolicyE
```

but because you are missing this symbol, you will not receive any results.

So your problem boils down to incompatible libraries with 1 of 2 solutions.  You can either find old/newer source for `libfastrtps.so` or older/newer source for `libsoss-dds.so`.  Ideally, if these packages are available via your distribution's package manager, use that to do the work for you.